# Prestashop ThemeConfigurator module - 5th element wrongly displayed

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm totally new in prestashop/themeconfigurator but I want to help my wife to solve problem with wrongly displayed banners on website. She added 6 banners using themeconfigurator module and it should look like this

```
b1 | b2 | b3
b4 | b5 | b6
```

but it looks like this

```
b1 | b2 | b3
b4 | b5
b6
```

I found that 5th banner has 66% width:

```
#htmlcontent_home ul li.htmlcontent-item-5 {
  width: 66.6667%; 
}
```

For me this style is redondant and I don't know why it is in css file (hooks.css). As I found on github site (https://github.com/PrestaShop/themeconfigurator/blob/master/sass/hooks.scss) this style is added by default.

So the question is - is it possible to change this style using admin panel or do I need to change hooks.css source code? The problem is that I haven't got access to server so I can't edit source code.

version: prestashop 1.6.0.6

Answer (score 0):

i see there is no options to change it.

in hooks.css
line no: 15

```
    #htmlcontent_home ul li.htmlcontent-item-5 {
        width: 66.6667%;
     }
```

you need to remove this line or overwrite it from your css files.